# Get account ID from Google Analytics Tracking code on page

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am performing an audit using a custom web crawler of mine and was trying to garner the accountID for the legacy implementations of Google Analytics, but I cannot seem to get any of the JavaScript functions in _gaq to return the accountId in use. Does anybody know how to do this? All the documentation I've read really only mentions how to set variables, not how to get variables out once set for the purpose of auditing an implementation.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

Thanks everyone! I wish I could check off all of your responses as good answers.

After a bit of testing, I have come up with the following function that handles pretty much every use case.

```
function getAccount() {
    try {
        if (_gaq) {
            for (i = 0; i < _gaq.length; i++) {
              if (_gaq[i][0] == "_setAccount") {
                  return _gaq[i][1]
              }
            }
        }
        if (_gat) {
            if (_gat.fb) {
                return _gat.fb
            }
        }
        if (ga) {
            return ga.getAll()[0].a.data.values[':trackingId']
        }
    } catch (e) { }
    return ""
}
```

Comment: hey but  _gaq.length == undefined

Comment: Oh boy, (long time since I saw this) but null checks were not such a big thing for me back then. Really, analytics code should always fail gracefully, and that is why the code is wrapped in a try/catch. The actual code caught the edge cases in order to record them as such, and that met with expectations. I just needed a function to reliably record the id in almost 100% of cases.

Comment: Just a note: I've used this today, and I get the results from
 ga.getAll()[INDEX_HERE].b 
instead of
 ga.getAll()[INDEX_HERE].a 
as in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are prepared to accept a less than elegant solution you could use

```
function getAccount(_gaq) {
    for (i = 0; i < _gaq.length; i++) {
        if (_gaq[i][0] == "_setAccount") {
            return _gaq[i][1];
        }
    }
}
```

`_gaq` is an array of arrays, the function simply loops through until it finds a subarray where the first element is `_setAccount` and returns the second element, which is the account number (`_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);`).

As you are talking of legacy implementations, there are even older versions of the code so you might need more checks. The oldest version I could find on an active page was:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
_uacct = "UA-XXXXXXXX-X";
urchinTracker();
</script>
```

It's quite easy to get the Account Id from there. There is also the synchronous version of the code (sorry, can't find an example right now).

And for the current version look at Petrs answer.

Answer (score 2):

Joshua, this isn't a standard feature / get function that would be available.

You can however manually access *ga* object created by the tracking library.

If you for example open console for this webpage and type in:

```
ga.getAll()[0].a.data.values[':trackingId']
```

You will receive *UA-5620270-1* which is probably the main Analytics Account for Stack Overflow. Similar approach should work in your case as well - and also any other attribute that's accessible:

Screen: http://fii.cz/sbdqevk

Comment: Since the OP was talking about "legacy" and "_gaq" I don't think this applies, "ga" belongs to Universal Analytics.

Comment: Actually, I thought the inclusion of the code for getting the tracking ID for Universal Analytics was very helpful. I would have posted my question as for both tracking libraries, but didn't want to be accused of asking a duplicate question.

Comment: On that note, my crawler is performing very well at its audit now. Thanks again y'all!

Comment: Joshua / Eike, now it seems we arrived at a very useful answer covering all tracking object versions :)

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ga-object-methods-reference) first you get all the trackers set on page

```
// returns an array with all the trackers
const trackers = ga.getAll();
```

And then, for each tracker, you can obtain the [tracking id](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#trackingId) for each one getting the property

```
// returns the 'trackingId' propperty
const trackingId = tracker.get('trackingId'));
```

If you want **to shorten it up**, you could do

```
const trackingIds = ga.getAll().map(tracker => tracker.get('trackingId'));
```

**Warning:**

Remember to run this always [after the *ga ready*](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ga-object-methods-reference#method-summary).

> Don't — use ga object methods outside a readyCallback as the methods
>   may not be available yet.
>
> `var trackers = ga.getAll();`
>
> Do — use ga object methods inside a
>   readyCallback as they're guaranteed to be available.
>
> `ga(function() {
>     var trackers = ga.getAll();
>   });`

Comment: Thanks, this was the only answer i could find that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I just did it using an alternative method, as follows:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(function() {
  var trackers, i;
  trackers = _gat._getTrackers();
  for (i = trackers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var account = trackers[i]._getAccount();
    console.log("tracker account", account);
  }
});
```